# Can I do something like RESTORE DATABASE <server>.<databasename>?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to restore a database on a server, using a script on another server?

For example, I have a server *A* and a server *B* and I want to restore a database *foo* on server *B* from within a script on server *A*.
I was thinking of something like this: `RESTORE DATABASE B.foo FROM DISK ...`, but I can't find any information about it.

And I'm looking for something similar for BACKUP DATABASE too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Most commands are specific to the local server.

Saying that, if you have a linked server, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer, 'RESTORE DATABASE foo FROM DISK ...; SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE();')
```

Edit, after comments

You could also run `EXEC MyLinkedServer.SomeDB.SomeSchema.MyRestoreWrapper ...`

Comment: While reading documentation on OPENQUERY, I found that you can also execute a stored procedure on a linked server. So if I were to put my restore script in a stored procedure, this should have the same result?

Comment: If the stored procedure was remote, yes

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
EXEC linkedserver.master.dbo.sp_executesql N'RESTORE DATABASE ...';
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this, using "`WITH MOVE...`"? Because, let's say I'm on SQL1 ( E:\ for data files ), but I want to restore the database into SQL2 ( F:\ data files ). if I use `MOVE 'Z' TO F:`, it says that the server does not havethis Drive. It will work "...`sp_executesql N'RESTORE DATABASE ...MOVE xyz TO F:\`" ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use WITH MOVE, but you need to add the argument for all files. I can't fix the code you have because, well, I can't see the code you have, nor do I know the drive layout of the destination server or the file specs for the database you're trying to restore.

Comment: You need to say `with move 'filename' to 'F:\path\file.mdf'` - you can't just say to F:\

Comment: Oh yes... I have the full Patch, it was just an example. I tested here and it worked very well. Thanks @aaron Bertnand